# Possible to generate a unique ID for every registration in django

Tags: python, django

I'm thinking of using registration_redux for user registrations for my side project. I want a unique alphanumeric code generated for every user registration. 
This is my custom generated sequence:

```
def Foogen():
    prefix = 'M'
    alphabets = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    for i in range(5):
        prefix +=str(random.choice(range(5)))

    for i in range(5):
        prefix +=str(random.choice(alphabets))

    return prefix
```

Does redux allow for such a flexibility? Currently , i'm just using a Merchant form + model for registration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a custom signal provided by `django-registration-redux` where you can add  a small bit of additional logic.

> [registration.signals.user_registered](http://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html#registration.signals.user_registered)